# Sublime Text 3 Show capitalized folders on top

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is it possible to sort the folders in the sidebar in a way, that shows capitalized folders on the top?

Answer (score 0):

The folders are shown in the order they are listed in the project. You can rearrange them as you see fit. Nothing built in, but you write a script to modify the sublime-project files so they look like what you want.